# questions about making a multi-language site as speedy and efficient as possible

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, frameworks, dry

I am making a site for a company, and they require both French and English languages.

I have a few theoretical questions to help me guide my development. The clientelle is mostly in remote areas where 56k dial-up is still prevalent, thus small download size/re-usability of material is key.

I plan on having the header and footer separate from content section on the pages, thus once header and footer are loaded, they are just re-used from user cache.

my main question is, should I have languages stored in a db and use session variables? (I suspect this to be the slowest) or in a language file and use the URI with language class?

Also, If I autoload the language file, does that mean it will be stored locally thus keeping bandwidth usage to a minimum?

Comment: If you generate the pages on the server with PHP and different language resource strings, then the client's download speed doesn't really matter.
Do the clients have to have *both* languages?

Comment: no the client doesn't have to have both, they choose at the first visit, and could always switch if needed.

so autoloading would not put the files on the clients machine and increase navigation speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details about the language will have such a minuscule affect on load times in comparison to any images the site may serve. If what you are looking to do is avoid the fractions of seconds required to query language from a database you could code the site such that it serves the entire site as flat text, which can be achieved many ways.

www.somesite.com/fr/ vs. www.somesite.com/en/

Or use either of the methods you mentioned in your post.

My point is that images are your main overhead. You can strip all images from a page and run benchmarks yourself to see that no matter how you serve language - from db or file/class you are looking at milliseconds of difference even on 56k. Assuming your pages are normal size and not hundreds of thousands of lines. One small image will likely take longer to load than all text on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Your header/footer plan will only work using frames and a far-future expiration date (though, I suppose sending a 304 header according to the If-Modified-Since would still help).

And no, the CI language config is server-side.  It has nothing to do with client-side bandwidth.

Most of what you're talking about deals with response headers.  Yahoo and Google have both created great resources for this information.